# CSS transition for a div on click

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I'm trying to display a div appear from top and flows downwards. I have achieved a similar effect using CSS transitions. But i want that div transition happen when i click a button. I'm coding this in reactjs.

I have done something like this

**my div**

```
<div className="notification_div">

                <span className="small_font notification_header">Notifications</span>

                <div className="notification_item_div">
                    <span className="notification_item">Test Notification</span>
                </div>

                <div className="notification_item_div">
                    <span className="notification_item">Test Notification</span>
                </div>

                <div className="notification_item_div">
                    <span className="notification_item">Test Notification</span>
                </div>

 </div>
```

**CSS i have applied**

```
.notification_div {

    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

.notification_div:active {

    transition: height 1s;
    height: 100%;

}
```

My div appears when i click a button.Only when i click the div, the transition begins to happen. I want the transition to happen when the div first appears itself.

How can i do this?

This how i show my div in reactjs

```
class App extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showNotification: false,
        };


            this.open_notification = this.open_notification.bind(this);
    }

    open_notification() {

        this.setState({
            showNotification: !this.state.showNotification,
        });

    }
```

Comment: `.notification_div:active` means that the css applies ONLY when the element is clicked on

Comment: yes i'm aware of that. I want to do the transition when my div appears.not clicked.

Comment: does your css actually make your div flow from top to bottom? Because changing the height shouldn't change the position of the div

Answer (score 0):

Well regardless of what effect you're trying to do, it's going to follow the following logic.

One way is to add another class when you click the function, like so... (I'm going add an id to the div so now it's `<div id="notification" className="notification_div">`)

```js
function open_notification() 
{
//    this.setState({
//        showNotification: !this.state.showNotification,
//    });
     document.getElementById("notification").className += " active";
}
```

```css
.notification_div {

    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

.notification_div.active {

    transition: height 1s;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="notification" class="notification_div">

                <span className="small_font notification_header">Notifications</span>

                <div className="notification_item_div">
                    <span className="notification_item">Test Notification</span>
                </div>

                <div className="notification_item_div">
                    <span className="notification_item">Test Notification</span>
                </div>

                <div className="notification_item_div">
                    <span className="notification_item">Test Notification</span>
                </div>

 </div>
 
 <button type="button" onclick="open_notification()">Click Me</button>
```

Note: You will need to change `class` to `className` in the HTML and maybe some other things. But it should generally be what you're looking for.